# get paths of the references listed a csproj file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, msbuild

I know the path of a csproj file (among 100s of other project files).
I want to check which references are present in the "bin", so that the "copy local" value of those references be set to false. For this, I need to get the paths of the references (or is there a better way??).
How can I get the Paths of the references listed in the csproj file?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Pretty unclear.  How do you hope to survive Build + Clean?  And what does the "Copy Local" property have to do with setting a WarningLevel?

Comment: I am building a tool which would check if an assembly reference is within the "bin", and accordingly set/reset the copy local value for the reference.
As for the warning level snippet, i want the reference path value to be retrieved in a similar manner (using LINQ, if possible)...

Comment: Also, I would like to know if there is a way to access the copy local attribute of a reference in its default state. That is, you cannot view/access the default copy local value (marked as <private> </private> in the xml) unless you change it manually in VS.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
var project = ProjectRootElement.Open(fileName);
var referenceElements = project.Items
    .Where(x => x.ItemType.Equals("Reference"))
    .Where(x => x.HasMetadata && x.Metadata.Any(m => m.Name.Equals("HintPath") && CheckLocation(m.Value)));

    foreach (var projectItemElement in referenceElements) 
    {
        var copyLocalElement = projectItemElement.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("CopyLocal"));
        if (copyLocalElement != null) 
        {
            copyLocalElement.Value = "false";
            continue;
        }
        projectItemElement.AddMetadata("CopyLocal", "false");
    }
```

Implement CheckLocation method as you need. I don't fully test this, but I hope it shows right way.

Comment: Thanks @pavel for the LINQ expression!!
But my question is more about the implementation of the CheckLocation() function...am not sure if we can get the path of the reference from the csproj file.

Comment: What should do CheckLocation function? In my example it's called with reference path as argument. `CheckLocation(m.Value)` - `m.Value` in my example is reference HintPath from csproj.